# Getting exif data from all images in a directory using PHP

Tags: php, metadata, exif

I am currently trying to display geolocation of images from a directory, I have managed to display a location for a single image however I'm not sure how to change the code so it reads several files opposed to one. Anyone know? Appreciate your responses.

`$exif = exif_read_data("DSCN0010.jpg", 'ANY_TAG', true);`

I have tried the following however this doesn't work

```
$exif = exif_read_data(".metadata images/", 'ANY_TAG', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `glob()` function to get an array of filenames that match a pattern. For example, `glob('images/*.jpeg')` will return an array of all the JPEG files in the “images” directory. Then you can loop through the filenames and extract the EXIF data from each file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scandir` to get array of files in the directory: http://php.net/scandir

And then use `exif_read_data` for each file individually.

Comment: function get_image_location($image = ''){
 $dir    = './metadata images';
 $files1 = scandir($dir);
    $exif = exif_read_data("files1", 'ANY_TAG', true);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  this gives me an error

Comment: Warning: exif_read_data() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in

Comment: you neet to loop over the results of `scandir()` and read exif info one by one